# php if statement with one of two conditions if( a < b) or (b=0)

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

I have some huge blocks of code and I would like to avoid using elseif so the question is : Is it possible to construct an IF function with two possibilities in the same statement ? 
something like

```
  if( a < b) or (b=0)
{
statement
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with elseif statement?

Comment: You mean like using the [OR || logical operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)? e.g. `if  (a<b || b==0)`

Comment: @ajreal you're missing an = sign, that's an assignment to b.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if( ($a < $b) || ($b==0) )
{
     //do something
}
```

or even better

```
if( ($a < $b) || (0==$b) )
{
     //do something
}
```

so you don't accidentally assign 0 to $b.

Comment: or even `if( $a < $b || $b==0 )`

Comment: Who assigns 0 to b when writing b == 0?

Comment: You can accidentally write b=0, like @ajreal did in his response about half an hour ago...

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ($a<$b) OR ($b == 0) )
{
  //do something
}
```

Parenthesis in this case are not necessary, just added for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
($a < $b ? 'a is smaller' : 'a equals or is greater');
```

Quick and easy, but not easily to maintain (personal opinion).